# How to handle/inform users about unrecoverable exceptions in an APP_INITIALIZER?

Tags: angular, typescript, initialization

My Angular5 app loads a config file from the backend during application initialization (APP_INITIALIZER). Since the app cannot be run without it, my goal is to show a message to the user that the config couldn't be loaded.

```
 providers: [ AppConfig,
        { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: (config: AppConfig) => () => config.load(), deps: [AppConfig], multi: true },
        { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
        { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: GlobalErrorHandler }]
```

The `AppConfig` class should load a config file from a backend service before the app loads:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppConfig {

    private config: Object = null;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    public getConfig(key: any) {
        return this.config[key];
    }


    public load() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.get(environment.serviceUrl + 'config/config')
                .catch((error: any) => {                  
                    return Observable.throw(error || 'Server error');
                })
                .subscribe((responseData) => {
                    this.config = responseData;
                    this.config['service_endpoint'] = environment.serviceUrl;                  
                    resolve(true);
                });
        });
    }
}
```

Global Exception handler:

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    constructor( private messageService: MessageService) { }
    handleError(error) {
        // the AppConfig exception cannot be shown with the growl message since the growl component is within the AppComponent
        this.messageService.add({severity: 'error', summary: 'Exception', detail: `Global Exception Handler: ${error.message}`});

        throw error;
    }

}
```

If the config file cannot be loaded, an exception is thrown, caught & rethrown in the global exception handler (uncaught HTTPErrorResponse in console.log()) and the loading spinner is hanging for ever)

Since the `AppComponent` does not get loaded (which is ok, since the app cannot be used without the configuration) and as my message/"growl" Component is a sub component of the `AppComponent`, I cannot display a message to the user.

Is there a way to show a message in the `index.html` page during this stage? I wouldn't like to redirect the user to a different .html page than the index.html, since the users will then just reload/f5 on the error.html.

Answer (score 18):

In main.ts I have changed bootstrap in this way:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
.catch(err => {
    // error should be logged into console by defaultErrorLogger, so no extra logging is necessary here
    // console.log(err);
    // show error to user
    const errorMsgElement = document.querySelector('#errorMsgElement');
    let message = 'Application initialization failed';
    if (err) {
        if (err.message) {
            message = message + ': ' + err.message;
        } else {
            message = message + ': ' + err;
        }
    }
    errorMsgElement.textContent = message;
});
```

any occurred exceptions are caught and message is set into an html element. The element is defined in index.html in app-root tag, e.g.

```
<app-root><div id="errorMsgElement" style="padding: 20% 0; text-align: center;"></div> 
</app-root>
```

The content of tag is replaced by angular, if bootstrap has been successful.

Comment: This is the correct answer!  Thank you for finally finding this -- I was trying to figure out where a rejection in `APP_INITIALIZER` winds up, and it turns out it throws out of `bootstrapModule`.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

I haven't found a good solution for a very similar issue too, but as a workaround, this is how I did it:

- Extend the config class with an `initialized` variable:

  ```
  @Injectable()
  export class AppConfig {       
      public settings: AppSettings = null;
      public initialized = false;

      public load() {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              this.http.get(environment.serviceUrl + 'config')
                  .catch((error: any) => {                      
                      this.initialized = false;
                      resolve(error);
                      return Observable.throw(error || 'Server error');
                  })
                  .subscribe((responseData: any) => {
                      this.settings = responseData;
                      this.initialized = true;
                      resolve(true);
                  });
          });
      }
  }
  ```
- And within the `app.component.html` I show either the app or an error message, depending on this variable:

  ```
  <div *ngIf="!appConfig.initialized">
      <b>Failed to load config!</b>
      <!-- or <app-config-error-page> -->
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="appConfig.initialized" #layoutContainer >
      <!-- the app content -->
  </div>
  ```
- The global exception handler:

  ```
  @Injectable()
  export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
      constructor( private notificationService: NotificationService) { }
      handleError(error) {
          this.notificationService.error('Exception', `${error.message}`);
          return Observable.throw(error);
      }  
  }
  ```

Of course one could also store the concrete error message / exception text in the config object and show it to the users in the app.component/error.page.component if needed.

Comment: What happens if the promise rejects? Does it still display the app.component.html.. If the initialization process fails?

Comment: In my case it does, yes. If the initialization / loading of the configuration fails, the exception is logged in the global error handler but the app.component is still loaded.

Comment: where is appConfig.initialized in the template decleared ?

Answer (score 5):

I have a slightly different approach to offer. In my opinion, we do *not* want the bootstrap of the Angular app to continue if we can't properly initialize it, since it won't work properly. Instead, we just want to display message to the user, and stop.

**Background**: in my initialization code, I have to make two asynchronous requests in a particular order:

1. I make an HTTP request to my "own" web server (where the Angular app is served from), to get the hostname of *second* web server that hosts my back-end API.
2. I then make a request to that second web server to retrieve further configuration information.

If either of those requests fail, then I need to stop and show a message rather than Angular continuing with the bootstrap process.

Here's a simplified version of my code *before* adding in the new exception handling (note that I prefer to use `Promise` and `async`/`await` rather than `Observable`, but that's not really relevant):

```
const appInitializer = (
  localConfigurationService: LocalConfigurationService,
  remoteConfigurationService: RemoteConfigurationService
): () => Promise<void> => {

  return async () => {
    try {
      const apiHostName = await localConfigurationService.getApiHostName();
      await remoteConfigurationService.load(apiHostName);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Failed to initialize the Angular app!", e);
    }
};

export const appInitializerProvider = {
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: appInitializer,
  deps: [LocalConfigurationService, RemoteConfigurationService],
  multi: true
};
```

That code will log the error to the console, but then continue with the bootstrap process - not what we want.

To modify this code to (a) display a message, and (b) stop the bootstrap process in its tracks, I added the following 3 lines immediately after that `console.error` call:

```
      window.document.body.classList.add('failed');

      const forever = new Promise(() => { }); // will never resolve
      await forever;
```

The first line simply adds the class 'failed' to the document `<body>` element. We'll see what effect that has in a moment.

The other two lines `await` a `Promise` that is never resolved - in other words, they wait forever. This has the effect of stalling the Angular bootstrap process, so the Angular app never appears.

The final change is in my `index.html` file (the HTML file that's loaded by the browser, and which "contains" the Angular app). Here's what it looked like *before* my changes:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My App</title>
  <base href="/">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

That "loading..." text within the `<app-root>` element is displayed while the Angular app is initialized, and is replaced with the app content once the bootstrap process is complete.

To ensure that an "oops!" message is shown if the app cannot be initialized, I've added a `<style>` block with some CSS styles, and some extra content within the `<app-root>` element:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My App</title>
  <base href="/">

  <style type="text/css">
    #failure-message {
      display: none;
    }

    body.failed #loading-message {
      display: none;
    }

    body.failed #failure-message {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
<app-root>
  <h1 id="loading-message">Loading...</h1>
  <h1 id="failure-message">Oops! Something went wrong.</h1>
</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

So now, the "loading..." message is displayed by default (to be replaced with the app content if initialization is successful), but the "oops!" message is displayed instead if the `<body>` element has the `failed` class - which is what we add in our exception handler.

Of course, you can do better than a simple `<h1>` tag - you can put any content you like in there.

The net effect of all this is that the browser displays "loading..." and then either the Angular app loads or the "loading..." text is replaced with "oops!".

Note that the URL isn't changed, so if you hit reload in the browser, it'll start from scratch and try to load the Angular app all over again - which is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would update your initializer catch rather than throwing toGlobalErrorHandler

```
   this.http.get(environment.serviceUrl + 'config/config')
        .catch((error: any) => {
            window.location.href = '/relativepath/different.html';
            return Observable.throw(error || 'Server error')
        })
        .subscribe((responseData) => {
            this.config = responseData;
            this.config['service_endpoint'] = environment.serviceUrl;
            resolve(true);
        });
```

Comment: This solution causes application circular redirect: app init->error(http)->redirect ---> app init->error (http)->redirect ---> app init->....

Comment: Did you add the static html file to '/relativepath/different.html' to handle the error, so you don't get circular redirect?

Comment: Yes I did add did that but the circular redirect is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it...

```ts
// app.module.ts

export function loadAppsettings(http: HttpClient) {
  return async () => {
    try {
      const as = await http
          .get<IAppsettings>(`//${window.location.host}/appsettings.json`)
          .toPromise();
      // `appsettings` is a global constant of type IAppsettings
      Object.assign(appsettings, as); 
      return as;
    }
    catch (e) {
      alert('Exception message...');
      throw e;
    }
  };
}

@NgModule({
  // ...
  providers: [
    // ...
    { 
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER, 
      useFactory: loadAppsettings, 
      multi: true, 
      deps: [HttpClient]
    },
  ]
})
export class AppModule { ... }
```

Hope it helps a little :-)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but I need error page .. not alert :)

Comment: Well, you can still use pure javascript to manipulate the DOM of your index page. For example, you can dynamically insert an iframe into the DOM and load your error page through that or just have a hidden error div in there for this occasion all along? :-)

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to redirect, you can create an error.html file inside your src folder. Then redirect user to that file after error.

After you created the error.html , in your angular.json file add it to assets so it won't load angular application and redirect it.

```
 "assets": [
       {
        "glob": "**/*",
        "input": "src/assets",
        "output": "/assets"
       },
       {
         "glob": "error.html",
         "input": "src",
         "output": "/"
       }
    ],
```

Then change your load function to

```
public load() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.get(environment.serviceUrl + 'config/config')
                .catch((error: any) => {                  
                    window.location.href = '/error.html';
                    return Observable.throw(error || 'Server error');
                })
                .subscribe((responseData) => {
                    this.config = responseData;
                    this.config['service_endpoint'] = environment.serviceUrl;                  
                    resolve(true);
                });
        });
    }
```

Comment: If I'm understanding it correctly, a redirect is exactly NOT wanted. If the app redirects to http://localhost:4200/error.html, the user might click reload and will be stuck on the error page. I think the user should stays on http://localhost:4200/#/ but an ErrorPage.Component is being shown to the user.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I used was to create an interceptor and an error service. The interceptor will catch all HTTP errors with certain status codes that I know are errors.

Interceptor Example

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { ErrorService } from '@app/@pages/error/error.service';

import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private errorSvc: ErrorService
    ) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        return next
            .handle(req)
            .pipe(
                catchError((error: any, resp: Observable<HttpEvent<any>>) => {
                    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && (error.status === 0 || error.status > 400)) {
                        this.errorSvc.setHttpError(error);
                        this.router.navigate(['/error']);
                    }
                    return throwError(error);
                })
            );
    }
}
```

Error Service Example

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { LocalStorageService } from 'angular-2-local-storage';

import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ErrorService {

    private error$: BehaviorSubject<HttpErrorResponse> = new BehaviorSubject(this.localStorageSvc.get<HttpErrorResponse>('error'));

    constructor(private localStorageSvc: LocalStorageService) { }

    setHttpError(error: HttpErrorResponse): void {
        this.localStorageSvc.set('error', error);
        this.error$.next(error);
    }

    getHttpError(): Observable<HttpErrorResponse> {
        return this.error$.asObservable();
    }
}
```

So how this works is that the interceptor will catch the error when you are trying to load configuration data through the APP_INITIALIZER. Having caught the error the application should be routed to an error page. The error service will use local storage and the rxjs Behavior Subject to maintain the state of the error. The error component will inject this service into its constructor and subscribe to it to display the error details.