# APP_INITIALIZER blocks loading of the App on error

Tags: angular, error-handling, promise, initializer

I'am catching the error in the Subscribe and the enclosing Promise.

```
    @Injectable()
    export class CountryListResolver {

        public countryList: Locale[];

        constructor(private portareServices: PortareServices) { }

        load() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.portareServices.getCountryList().subscribe((data) => {
                    this.countryList = data;
                    resolve(true);
                },
                error => {
                    console.log('CountryListResolver', error);
                },
                () => {
                    // No errors, route to new page
                });
            }).catch((err: any) => Promise.resolve());
        }
    }
```

Now the thing is, when I uncomment the functionality of actually getting the data from the service, the app just loads fine (obviously without having the data in place which should have neen loaded initially).

```
  // this.localesEU = this.portareDataModel.setLocalesEU = this.countryListResolver.countryList;
```

App loads just fine when commented out the `load` function. Also, if service resolves succesfully, everything just works like a charm.

```
  providers: [
      CountryListResolver, { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: countryListProviderFactory, deps: [CountryListResolver], multi: true }
  ]
```

How to handle this issue?

Comment: `.catch((err: any) => Promise.resolve());` does `Promise.reject()` help?

Comment: this makes more sense, this led me i the right direction. thx.

Comment: If you prefer promises over observables you can use the `topromise` operator https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html

Answer (score 1):

Per [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56021193/26286), when `APP_INITIALIZER` rejects, it falls out of the promise returned by `bootstrapModule`:

```
// main.ts

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
.catch(err => { ... fail gracefully });
```